# Is there any point in globals or 'evil' singletons

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, actionscript, global

I previously used Singletons for global classes, if it's absolutely necessary i.e. logging, error handling.  But I am now using unit testing which doesn't like these!

I would like to ask a basic question on globals.  What's the point in them?  What's wrong with creating a new instance of a class when you need it?

Comment: "I would like to ask a basic question on globals. What's the point in them? What's wrong with creating a new instance of a class when you need it?"

I think I don't understand your question. There is nothing wrong with creating a new instance of a class when you need it...

Comment: Let me try to clarify by giving an example:  With an application that uses logging in every single class, is it not a bad idea to instantiate the log class every time, as opposed to using a singleton which accesses the same instance of the logging class?  Presumably this will use more memory?  I feel like I have some knowledge but am missing the basics! @iuiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true, sometimes singletons can create problems, that you won't have without them.

I try to give you a list of my thoughts on this matter:

- The most severe would be, that your software has circular dependencies. If you are working on a SOA architecture it can happen quite fast, if you are not careful.
- Also singletons can often lead to very close coupling of your classes, which makes you job as a tester really really hard.
- If you work on a big project and the way another class can get an instance of your Singleton changes, you will have to change lots of code. This can also happen without singletons, but I have the feeling, that it happens more often with singletons.

But sometimes a singleton is a nice idea and you should stick to it. Even in AS3 you can use singletons with the famous private class argument constructor workaround. As a heuristic when not to use singletons, i would suggest thinking about, if the class needs lots of references to other singletons.
And with some thinking you can also make your singletons testable.

Answer (score 4):

you should read this SO thread:  [What is so bad about Singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

personally, i'm all for singletons for things like logging, undo/redo stacks, localization and notifications from one display list branch to another - when event bubbling isn't really an option.

while they're not always ideal, singletons certainly have their place and can make development a lot easier, regardless of what some purists might say.